# Angular 5 webpack

Tags: webpack, angular5

index.html always shows loading ... in the "my-app" tag and does not load the app.component.
why ???

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <title>Angular With Webpack</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    {{2+2}}
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

i tried run {{2+2}} but this is dose not count

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

//import '../assets/css/styles.css';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: require('./app.component.html'),
 // styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 }
```

Comment: Is there any errors?

Comment: no, command line clean

Comment: I don't know anything about Angular, but shouldn't you load some Angular related libraries anywhere?

Comment: angularjs has library

Comment: i download example from this https://angular.io/guide/webpack

Comment: but can not run

Comment: someone has encountered such ?